# Create a list of every country where we have customers but not suppliers

Tags: sql

So I have to make a query where we have only customers in a country by no suppliers

```
Select Distinct s.ContactName as ShippersName, s.Country as Location,
      c.ContactName as CustomersName,  c.Country as Location
 From Suppliers s
 Join Customers c 
       On s.Country != c.Country
  Where c.country not in (s. country)
  order by c.country
```

I got the results, but its giving me where they aren't equal...
I just want the country that only has customers. Is there like a special keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.country
       FROM customers c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM suppliers s
                                WHERE s.country = c.country);
```

Comment: Why not modify your subquery to `SELECT TOP 1 country FROM suppliers` since it only matters if one record exists and the query will finish quicker that way?

Comment: @daShier: The selected values don't matter with a subquery introduced by `EXISTS`, it won't be faster it won't be slower it just doesn't matter as the engine really just checks for the existence and finishes once a row is found anyways. And I consider `*` to be the easiest on the eye but that's opinion based of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get customer records where the country is not in the supplier table, then the first columns of your result set can be removed since they will always be NULL:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.ContactName AS CustomersName,  c.Country AS Location
      FROM customers c
      LEFT JOIN Suppliers s
      ON c.Country = s.Country
      WHERE s.country IS NULL
      ORDER BY c.country
```